# How can Ngrok tunnel when ufw denies the port

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, ufw

This is a theoric question: I'm on Linux Ubuntu 20 and I've installed **ngrok** tunneling service to let my computer be reached from outside my local area network.

I've started locally a webserver on **http://localhost:8080** and started **ngrok http tunneling on port 8080**, so I got HTTP and HTTPS endpoints to reach my service from the web.

My service **is reachable** from the public http/https URL given by ngrok service. I've checked the firewall rules on my laptop where the webserver and ngrok are running and this is what I can strangely see:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     DENY        Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     DENY        Anywhere                  
8080/tcp                   DENY        Anywhere                  
22                         DENY        Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                DENY        Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                DENY        Anywhere (v6)             
8080/tcp (v6)              DENY        Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    DENY        Anywhere (v6)
```

I expected to have to ufw allow port 8080 before tunneling, but it wasn't necessary at all.
How can ngrok make this port accessible if there is an explicit rule which deny its access from outside?

Comment: You only denied tcp but not http, this could be the reason.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is it really 20 or is it 20.04 or 20.10? It may not affect this answer but you need to be clear.